# cordova-gallery-api plugin hangs the app while trying to call getMedia

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using Ionic 3 for my app and using cordova-gallery-api plugin i'm trying to get the data from iOS Gallery. But app hangs on the galleryAPI.getMedia function call.

```
galleryAPI.getAlbums(function (items) {
            console.log(items);
            if (items[0]) {
                galleryAPI.getMedia(items[0].title, function (media) {
                    console.log(media);
                });
            }
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

I can see the albums array returned from getAlbums. But app crashes/hangs right after.

Anyone used this plugin? Any help?

Comment: Can you add the crash logs to your question?

Comment: @Umbo Unfortunately i cannot post it due to company policy